# Property or method "key" is not defined on the instance - Vue/Laravel application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an application in which on deleting one of the registers i receive the message following Vue-warn:

> Property or method "key" is not defined on the instance but referenced
>   during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the
>   data option or for class-based components, by initializing the
>   property.

Only initializing the variable key on the data/return didn't actually solve my problem.

Another thing i noticed is that the data is deleted from the DB, the field log.title and log.user are deleted from the the logs list straight away but the other half of the row still remain on the view until I leave and reenter the Log component. Not sure if the above Vue-warn has something to do with this delete/viewing bug, but it might be.

I would appreciate if someone could give me a clue on what is going on?

This is my Log.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">

        <log-show-detail v-if="logModalOpen" :logUser="logUser" :logTitle="logTitle" :logType="logType" :logDescription="logDescription" :logDate="logDate" @closeRequest='close'> </log-show-detail>

        <log-edit v-if="editModalOpen" :logId="logId" :logUser="logUser" :logTitle="logTitle" :logType="logType" :logDescription="logDescription" :logDate="logDate" @closeRequest='close'></log-edit>

        <div class="form-group">
                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" placeholder="Filter the Logs"> -->
                <br>
                <i class="fas fa-plus jobs-page" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"></i>
                <div v-if="isLoading" class="loading-image">
                    <img src="/develogger-app/public/img/dev-tick.gif" alt="">
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row content-holder">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="left-align">
                        <th class="">Log</th>
                        <th class="">User</th>
                        <th class="center-align" style="text-align:right">Date</th>

                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="log in logs" :key="log.id" :log="log" @deleteLog="deleteLog" class="tr-table">
                        <td class="client-name" @click="openLogs(log.id,log.user,log.title,log.type,log.description,log.created_at)">{{ log.title }}</td>
                        <td class="" >{{ log.user }}</td>
                        <td class="client-pm" style="text-align:right">{{moment(log.created_at).fromNow()}}</td>
                        <!-- <td @click="openEdit(log.id,log.user,log.title,log.type,log.description,log.created_at)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td> -->
                        <td @click="deleteLog(key,log.id)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>


        <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Create new Log</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">

                            <input v-model="log.title" name="website" type="text" id="website" class="form-control" placeholder="Log Title"><br>

                            <select v-model="log.domain_id" id="type" class="form-control" name="type"><br>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Website</option>
                                <option value="1">aerogen.com</option>
                                <option value="4">ardsolus.ie</option>
                                <option value="8">blacklionrealstate.fund</option>
                                <option value="11">blanchadstowncentre.ie</option>
                                <option value="7">chathamandking.ie</option>
                                <option value="5">clayfarm.ie</option>
                                <option value="10">edenplaza.ie</option>
                                <option value="6">hardwicke.ie</option>
                                <option value="2">kennedywilsonresidential.ie</option>
                                <option value="3">loulerie.ie</option>                              
                                <option value="9">procert.ie</option>  
                            </select>

                            <br>

                            <select v-model="log.type" id="type" class="form-control" name="type"><br>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
                                <option>Client Update</option>
                                <option>Dev Update</option>
                                <option>Bug</option>
                                <option>Style Fix</option>
                            </select>

                            <br>

                            <label class="left" for="description">Log Description:</label>
                                <textarea v-model="log.description" class="form-control" rows="5" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                            <br>

                            <div class="left">
                                <input  v-model="tell" type="checkbox" name="tell-everyone" id="tell-everyone">
                                <label for="description">Tell Everyone?</label>
                                <br>
                                <input v-model="checked" type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" value="checked">
                                <label for="checked">Resolved and Tested?</label>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button :disabled="!checked || !isComplete" id="log-it" type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-xl" data-dismiss="modal" @click="save">
                            <span v-if="checked && isComplete" id="button-content"><b>LOG IT</b></span>
                            <span v-else id="button-content"><b>FIX IT</b></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';
import moment from 'moment';
import ShowDetail from './ShowDetail.vue';
import EditLog from './EditLog.vue';

    export default {

        name:'Log',

        data(){
            return {
                key:0,
                logModalOpen: false,
                editModalOpen: false,
                isLoading:'',
                checked:false,
                tell:false,
                logs: [],
                log: {id:'', domain_id:'', title: '', type: '', description: ''},
                csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
                errors:{},

                //passing those variables to ShowDetails component
                logId:'',
                logUser:'',
                logTitle:'',
                logType:'',
                logDescription:'',
                logDate:'',
            }
        },

        methods:{

            getLogs(){
                window.axios.get('/develogger-app/public/api/logs').then(({data})=>{
                    data.forEach(log =>{
                        this.logs.push(log)
                    });
                });
            },

            moment,

            save(){
                this.isLoading = true;
                if(this.log.title.length > 0 && this.log.domain_id.length > 0 && this.log.type.length > 0 && this.log.description.length > 0){

                    window.axios.post('/develogger-app/public/api/logs',this.log).then((response) => {
                        this.logs.push(response.data)
                        this.log.domain_id = '';
                        this.log.title = '';
                        this.log.type = '';
                        this.log.description = '';
                        this.checked = false;

                        setTimeout(() => {
                            this.isLoading = false;
                        }, 800);

                    }).catch((error) => this.errors = error.response.data.errors)

                }

            },

            openLogs(id,user,title,type,description,date){
                this.logId = id;
                this.logUser = user;
                this.logTitle = title;
                this.logType = type;
                this.logDescription = description;
                this.logDate = date;
                this.logModalOpen = true;
            },

            openEdit(id,user,title,type,description,date){
                this.logId = id;
                this.logUser = user;
                this.logTitle = title;
                this.logType = type;
                this.logDescription = description;
                this.logDate = date;
                this.editModalOpen = true;
            },

            close(){
                this.logModalOpen = false;
                this.editModalOpen = false;
            },

            deleteLog(key,id){

                if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){
                    this.isLoading = true;

                    window.axios.delete(`/develogger-app/public/api/logs/${id}`,this.log).then((response) => {
                            this.logs.push(response.data)
                            this.logs.splice(key,1);

                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.isLoading = false;
                            }, 800);

                            this.logId = '';

                        }).catch((error) => this.errors = error.response.data.errors)
                }

            }

        },

        created(){
            this.getLogs();
        },

        computed: {
            isComplete () {
                return this.log.title && this.log.domain_id && this.log.type && this.log.description;
            }
        },

        components:{
            'log-show-detail': ShowDetail,
            'log-edit': EditLog,
        }

    }



</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

- `v-for="log in logs"` to `"v-for="(log, index) in logs"`
- `<td @click="deleteLog(key, log.id)"...` to `<td @click="deleteLog(index, log.id)"`

```js
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(log, index) in logs" :key="log.id" :log="log" @deleteLog="deleteLog" class="tr-table">
      <td class="client-name" @click="openLogs(log.id,log.user,log.title,log.type,log.description,log.created_at)">{{ log.title }}</td>
      <td class="" >{{ log.user }}</td>
      <td class="client-pm" style="text-align:right">{{moment(log.created_at).fromNow()}}</td>
      <!-- <td @click="openEdit(log.id,log.user,log.title,log.type,log.description,log.created_at)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td> -->
      <td @click="deleteLog(index,log.id)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Well, the error continues. I also tried <td @click="deleteLog(log.id,index)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td> in the end, but no news so far. Still the same

Comment: ok, can you print/console the `key` & `id` inside `deleteLog(key,id){`?

Comment: It doesn't display any value, only shows the same Vue-warn error. even if i pass as parameter only the log.id the Vue-warn error is show on the console.

Comment: ok, can you create a JSFiddle example so, it will be very helpful to find the problem?

Comment: I think i found the answer and that was so Silly...if you look at my delete() function, i have copied some function to be executed inside the promisse from the save() method and i forgot to delete: this.logs.push(response.data)...This function sgouldnt be there, right?

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to help me @Sajib Khan